# django gunicorn sock file not created by wsgi

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a basic django rest application in my digital ocean server (Ubuntu 16.04) with a local virtual environment.
The basic wsgi.py is:

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "workout_rest.settings")

# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

# Apply WSGI middleware here.
# from helloworld.wsgi import HelloWorldApplication
# application = HelloWorldApplication(application)
```

I have followed step by step this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

When I test Gunicorn's ability to serve the project with this command:
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application
All works well.

So I've tried to setup Gunicorn to use systemd service file. 
My /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service file is:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ben
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ben/myproject
ExecStart=/home/ben/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ben/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My Nginx configuration is:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ben/myproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ben/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

I've changed listen port from 80 to 8000 because 80 give me a err_connection_refused error.
After starting the server with this command:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

When I try to run my website, I get an 502 Bad Gateway error.
I've tried these commands (found on the tutorial comments):

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start gunicorn
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

but nothing changes.
When I take a look at the Nginix logs with this command:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

I can read that sock file doesn't exists:

```
2016/10/07 09:00:18 [crit] 24974#24974: *1 connect() to unix:/home/ben/myproject/myproject.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.197.20.27, server: 139.59.150.116, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/ben/myproject/myproject.sock:/", host: "server_ip_adress:8000"
```

Why this sock file isn't created? How can I configure django/gunicorn to create this file?
I have added gunicorn in my INSTALLED_APP in my Django project but it doesn't change anything.

**EDIT:**

When I test the nginx config file with `nginx -t` I get an error: `open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)`.
But if I run the command with sudo: `sudo nginx -t`, the test is successful. Does that mean that I have to allow 'ben' user to run Ngnix?

About gunicorn logfile, I cannot find a way to read them. Where are they stored?

When I check whether gunicorn is running by using `ps aux | grep gunicorn`:

```
ben      26543  0.0  0.2  14512  1016 pts/0    S+   14:52   0:00 grep --color=auto gunicorn
```

Here is hat happens when you run the systemctl enable and start commands for gunicorn:

```
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn
Synchronizing state of gunicorn.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable gunicorn

sudo systemctl start gunicorn
I get no output with this command

sudo systemctl is-active gunicorn
active

sudo systemctl status gunicorn
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2016-10-06 15:40:29 UTC; 23h ago

Oct 06 15:40:29 DevUsine systemd[1]: Started gunicorn.service.
Oct 06 18:52:56 DevUsine systemd[1]: Started gunicorn.service.
Oct 06 20:55:05 DevUsine systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Oct 06 20:55:17 DevUsine systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Oct 06 21:07:36 DevUsine systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Oct 06 21:16:42 DevUsine systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Oct 06 21:21:38 DevUsine systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Oct 06 21:25:28 DevUsine systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Oct 07 08:58:43 DevUsine systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Oct 07 15:01:22 DevUsine systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
```

Comment: does anything of the following turn up an error? 1. Test the nginx config file with `nginx -t`. 2. Check the gunicorn logfile. 3. Check whether gunicorn is running by using, e.g., `ps aux | grep gunicorn`. If any of these turn up an error please add to your question.

Comment: What happens when you run the systemctl enable and start commands for gunicorn? And what do you see when you do `sudo systemctl is-active gunicorn` or `sudo systemctl status gunicorn`?

Comment: @Ben post what you're seeing at `/var/log/syslog`. Did you set the firewall correctly using `sudo ufw delete allow 8000` and `sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full'`? Is the nginx file you posted correctly symlinked to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`?

Comment: @YPCrumble `/var/log/syslog` is empty. Yes I've set the firewall correctly using `sudo ufw delete allow 8000` and `sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full'`. And my nginx file is correctly symlinked to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`. (If I run this command `ls -l /etc/nginx/sites-enabled` myproject file is highlighted in yellow.)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I had to change the permissions of my sock folder:

```
sudo chown ben:www-data /home/ben/myproject/
```

Another thing is that I have changed the sock location after reading in many post that it's not a good pratice to keep the sock file in the django project.
My new location is:

```
/home/ben/run/
```

Don't forget to change permissions:

```
sudo chown ben:www-data /home/ben/run/
```

To be sure that gunicorn is refreshed, run these commands:

```
pkill gunicorn
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start gunicorn
```

That will kill the gunicorn processes and start new ones.

You can run this command to make the process start at server boot:

```
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn
```

All works well now.

Comment: Thank you!! I was following this tutorial, and I spent two hours setting up an azure VM, anyways and kept getting 502 Bad Gateway. the tutorial is here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

sudo chown user:www-data
solved it!!

Comment: Important notes that should be added in the mentioned tutorial. Thx for sharing.

Comment: It is important to note that if you need to do this, that means gunicorn is running as root which is not recommended. You can specify the group and user in the gunicorn command with the flags `--user` and `--group`. Here is how it would look in your case:
`exec gunicorn --user ben --group www-data --bind unix:/home/ben/myproject/myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi`

Comment: This is the accpted answer but still has not addressed the issue of running the server as root which is not something you should ever do in production.

Comment: PLEASE update this answer it encourages bad practice! You should not just let your gunicorn server run as `root`

Comment: @ThisGuyCantEven don't hesitate to update the answer by yourself (you can suggest edition even if you are not the answer author).

Answer (score 5):

While the accepted answer works, there is one (imo major) issue with it, which is that the gunicorn web server is (probably) running as root, which is not recommended. The reason you end up needing to chown the socket is because it is owned by `root:root`, because that is the user/group your init job assumes by default. There are multiple ways to get your job to assume another role. As of this time (with gunicorn 19.9.0), in my opinion, the simplest solution to this is to use the `--user` and `--group` flags provided as part of the `gunicorn` command. This means your server can start with the user/group you specify. In your case:

`exec gunicorn --user ben --group www-data --bind unix:/home/ben/myproject/myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi`

will start gunicorn under `ben:www-data` user and create a socket owned by `ben:www-data` with the permissions `770`, or read/write/execute privilege for the user `ben` and group `www-data` on the socket, which is exactly what you ned in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have given path to the sock file outside my project. I needed to just create the directory so that the gunicorn can create the file inside that directory as I had had mentioned that path in the .services file. Basically, I made sure that I had all directories existing according to the path in the .services file. No need to change permissions or ownership

Answer (score -2):

Try run

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start gunicorn
sudo systemctl status gunicorn.service
```

The last line helped me to re-create .scok file

Comment: unknown operation gunicorn.service.
The syntax of the last line is not correct.