# Gunicorn listening to sock file that doesn't exist

Tags: nginx, flask, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I am trying to serve a Flask app on an Amazon EC2 instance using Gunicorn and nginx. I've been following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) with some slight modifications since I'm not on an Ubuntu machine. The EC2 instance is running RHEL Fedora. I'm not sure why nginx is not routing traffic on 80 to Gunicorn.

When I activate my virtual environment and start Gunicorn with:

`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --user ec2-user --workers 2 wsgi:app`

I can successfully access my app by visiting `http://[mydomain].co:5000`. However, when I change `bind` to listen to a sock file:

`gunicorn --bind unix:/home/ec2-user/run/myApp.sock --user ec2-user --group ec2-user --workers 2 wsgi:app`

and add the following file in my `/etc/nginx/sites-available`:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name [mydomain].co www.[mydomain].co;

        location / {
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ec2-user/run/myApp.sock;
        }
}
```

I can't access my site. I initially had a feeling that problem was that apparently no sock file was being created, because when I `ls /home/ec2-user/run/` the directory is empty. I tried instead to have gunicorn listen at `127.0.0.1:5000` and change my sites nginx conf file to `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000` just to see if that might work but also no luck.

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39919053/django-gunicorn-sock-file-not-created-by-wsgi) that mentioned changing the permissions of the folder inside which you place your sock file, but I don't think thats my issue here. The permissions of that folder are:

`drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Jun 13 02:44 /home/ec2-user/run/`

FWIW, when I start gunicorn binding to the sock file, it starts without error and says it is listening at that sock file location, the only thing is there doesn't appear to be any file there, so I'm very lost. I appreciate any and all help or clarification.

**EDIT 1**

The Linux distribution of my EC2 instance is RHEL Fedora, so I don't have a `systemd` or any related commands as contained in the linked tutorial. I have however created a service file but it's located under `\etc\init.d\` and when I run it `\etc\init.d\myservice start\` the output is:

```
[2020-06-13 13:31:46 +0000] [24177] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-06-13 13:31:46 +0000] [24177] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/home/ec2-user/run/reformapp.sock (24177)
[2020-06-13 13:31:46 +0000] [24177] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-06-13 13:31:46 +0000] [24180] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 24180
[2020-06-13 13:31:46 +0000] [24181] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 24181
```

and yet, when I exit out and run `ls /home/ec2-user/run/` there are no files there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a permission issue. In my ec2 machine I did this and worked for me.

Create a systemd service file

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/myapi.service
```

The file content as below:

```
[Unit]
Description=this is my test flask api
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ec2-user
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/flaskapp
Environment="PATH=/path/to/flaskapp/.env/bin"
ExecStart=/path/to/flaskapp/.env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:myapi.sock -m 007 wsgi
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then start the service

```
sudo systemctl enable myapi
sudo systemctl start myapi
sudo systemctl status myapi
```

By now you should be able to see the socket file in your flaskapp directory
Then you can create a nginx config

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapi
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapi /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

myapi.conf

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/path/to/flaskapp/myapi.sock;
    }
}
```

The server_name "_" indicates that this server catches all the possible values.

```
sudo chmod 710 /home/ec2-user
sudo usermod -aG ec2-user nignx
```

restart the service and test the url

```
sudo nginx -t
sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo systemctl status nginx
curl http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Unfortunately, my EC2 instance is running RHEL Fedora, so most of those Linux commands and locations don't exist. I don't have `systemd` or a `systemctl` command. I created a system service file similar to yours, but it's located in `/etc/init.d/myservice`. I added some additional information in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same problem earlier, and couldn't find the result anywhere.
I could see the logs and it was saying the permissions issue.
Even after giving the proper permissions, the issue would persist.

So I went for hit and trial.

And the solution was quite simple.
Give the location of .sock file elsewhere, for example /run/gunicorn_1.sock.
In my assumption, the process calling the file was not able to get past the ec2-user directory.

Hope I saved someone's time and energy.